# How do ulimit settings impact Linux?

Tags: linux, ulimit

Lately, I had a `EAGAIN` error with some async code that made me take a closer look at `ulimit` settings. While I clearly understand certain limits, such as `nofile`, others are still quite confused to me.

It's quite easy to find resources on how to set those, but I couldn't find any article explaining precisely what each setting is about and how that could impact the system.

Definition taken from `/etc/security/limits.conf` is not really self-explanatory:

```
- core - limits the core file size (KB)
- data - max data size (KB)
- fsize - maximum filesize (KB)
- memlock - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
- nofile - max number of open files
- rss - max resident set size (KB)
- stack - max stack size (KB)
- cpu - max CPU time (MIN)
- nproc - max number of processes
- as - address space limit (KB)
- maxlogins - max number of logins for this user
- maxsyslogins - max number of logins on the system
- priority - the priority to run user process with
- locks - max number of file locks the user can hold
- sigpending - max number of pending signals
- msgqueue - max memory used by POSIX message queues (bytes)
- nice - max nice priority allowed to raise to values: [-20, 19]
- rtprio - max realtime priority
- chroot - change root to directory (Debian-specific)
```

So I'd be glad if someone could enlighten me on those rather important Linux settings!

The error I face is actually:

```
{ [Error: spawn mediainfo EAGAIN]
  code: 'EAGAIN',
  errno: 'EAGAIN',
  syscall: 'spawn mediainfo',
  path: 'mediainfo',
  spawnargs: 
   [ '--Output=XML',
     '/home/buzut/testMedia' ],
  cmd: 'mediainfo --Output=XML /home/buzut/testMedia' }
```

As per the definition on [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html):

> An operation that would block was attempted on an object that has non-blocking mode selected. Trying the same operation again will block until some external condition makes it possible to read, write, or connect (whatever the operation).

I understand that `EAGAIN` error refers to a resource that is temporarily not available. It wouldn't be wise to set all parameters to `unlimited`. Thus I would understand the implication of which params to identify the one blocking and adjust – `ulimit` settings, my code or both – accordingly.

Here are my current limits:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127698
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 64000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 127698
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have made my homework and (almost) found what each option does. Also, I've noted that there is more options in `/etc/security/limits.conf` than it appears with `ulimit -a`. Therefore, I've only documented the latter here. Of course, everyone is invited to enrich this answer!

- **core file size**          (blocks, -c)

  The maximum size of core files created.
  Core dump is a system snapshot (RAM + context switch + processor registers).

  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump

---

- **data seg size**          (kbytes, -d)

  The maximum size of a process's data segment.
  a data segment is a portion of an object file or the corresponding virtual address space of a program that contains initialized static variables.

  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment

---

- **scheduling priority**             (-e)

  The maximum scheduling priority ("nice") a process can be given.

  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29

---

- **file size**               (blocks, -f)

  The  maximum  size  of files written by the shell and its children.

---

- **pending signals**                 (-i)

  Set of signals that are pending for delivery to the calling thread.

  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197600/what-are-pending-signals

---

- **max locked memory**       (kbytes, -l)

  The maximum size that may be locked into memory.
  Memory locking ensures the memory is always in RAM and never moved to the swap disk.

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818755/why-would-we-need-to-lock-a-processs-address-space-in-ram

---

- **max memory size**         (kbytes, -m)

  How much memory a process currently has in main memory (RAM), opposed to how much virtual memory the process has in total.

  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size

---

- **open files**                      (-n)

  The maximum number of open file descriptors.
  A file descriptor is an abstract indicator used to access a file or other input/output resource, such as a pipe or network socket.

  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor

  List file descriptors: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-procfs-file-descriptors.html

---

- **pipe size**            (512 bytes, -p)

  Pipe's internal buffer size. See "pipe capacity" section in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html

---

- **POSIX message queues**     (bytes, -q)

  The maximum number of bytes in POSIX message queues.
  POSIX message queues allow processes to exchange data in the form of messages.

  http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview

  Message queues in general https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue

---

- **real-time priority**              (-r)

  The maximum real-time scheduling priority.
  A realtime priority thread can never be pre-empted by timer interrupts and runs at a higher priority than any other thread in the system.

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663993/what-is-the-realtime-setting-for-for-process-priority

---

- **stack size**              (kbytes, -s)

  The maximum stack size.
  The stack size is a reserved region of memory that is used to store the location of function calls in order to allow return statements to return to the correct location.

  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation

---

- **cpu time**               (seconds, -t)

  The maximum amount of cpu time in seconds.

  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time

---

- **max user processes**              (-u)

  The  maximum  number  of processes a user can start or fork.

  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29

  This command shows how much processes each user is currently using:

  `ps h -Led -o user | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

---

- **virtual memory**          (kbytes, -v)

  The maximum amount of virtual memory  available to the shell.
  Virtual memory maps memory addresses used by a program, called virtual addresses, into physical addresses in computer memory.

  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

---

- **file locks**                      (-x)

  File locking is a mechanism that restricts access to a computer file by allowing only one user or process access at any specific time.

  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't mention what's your exact problem with limitation in Linux so it would be hard to fix it.
You use `ulimit -a` for check all of you limitation in OS. Also you can change every limitation you have  ( you can decrease it not increase except root can do anything )
Try to look at `man ulimit` to find out which option you need to change.

Comment: I edited my question to make my problem clearer. But beside that, I'd be glad to know which param does what (like `nofile` is the number of files a given user can have open simultaneously)!

Comment: `Unlimited` didn't fix your problem ?

Comment: I didn't try `unlimited` so far. I changed `nofiles` from `1024` to `64000`, but it didn't solve my problem. And I'd rather not change what I don't understand. And clearly, I don't know what others do…

Comment: Only option you shouldn't change is `core` !!! Core is env + bug log of applications. Put it on default (zero ) if you don't your disk will be full soon. First check your limitation `ulimit -a` then try `unlimited`

Comment: All right, I'm going to try as you suggest! Could you point me to a resource explaining what each option does (as you explained for `core`)?

Comment: I don't know what kind of resource you mean but options  `cpu` ( how much user take CPU for its process ) and `nproc` ( max number of process user can make or fork ) . Hope these will help you. Have fun ;)

Comment: I was looking for a resource explaining each option in plain english, just as you did for `cpu`, `nproc` and `core`! As neither `man ulimit` nor `/etc/security/limits.conf` file made that clear to me. Thank you for your explanations!